# Azure Webjobs not working with "VNet Route All Enabled"

Tags: c#, azure, network-programming

We currently have an .NET 6 Azure Web App that has several Web Jobs. This Web App is integrated in a vnet/subnet and we have it set up to route all traffic using the network configuration.

This Web app, and its corresponding Web Jobs do HTTP calls to an API (A Kubernetes Cluster hosted by someone else), that has the outgoing IP address of the Web App whitelisted.

[image]

This setup works for the Web App code, and makes it so that the outgoing IP of the calls the Web App makes are always the same single IP address of the VNet, so we can talk to the API using our whitelisted IP as normal.

However, calls made from the Web Jobs in this same Web App resource fail with a 403, leading me to believe that the Vnet Routing setting mentioned above does not work for the Web Jobs code.

How can we route outbound traffic from Web Jobs through the same network as the web app in the same website-resource?

Answer (score 0):

This could be a DNS resolution issue. When you integrate a Web App with a VNET, the DNS setting at the VNET level is used. Do you use private DNS zones? Are they linked to the VNET?

Can you ensure that the IP from the WebJob is the same as the outbound IP of the parent ASP?

Do you have Proxy setup for the WebJob? This could make it appear with a different IP.

If none of these suggestions bring you any new information, try opening a support ticket with Azure.